# How to Detect Mac OS X Version in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, macos, browser, operating-system, detect

I have scoured everywhere on the internet as to how to detect the OS and it's version. I have found out how to do it for windows, (see code below), and now I want it to work for Mac too.

Windows detection code (works perfectly!):

```
// OS detection
var _os_ = (function(){
var userAgent = navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase();
return {
    isWin2K: /windows nt 5.0/.test(userAgent),
    isXP: /windows nt 5.1/.test(userAgent),
    isVista: /windows nt 6.0/.test(userAgent),
    isWin7: /windows nt 6.1/.test(userAgent),
};
}());

// get OS shorthand names

var OS;
if(_os_.isWin2K){
OS = "Windows 2000";
}

if(_os_.isXP){
OS = "Windows XP";
}

if(_os_.isVista){
OS = "Windows Vista";
}

if(_os_.isWin7){
OS = "Windows 7";
}

alert(OS);
```

So I'm wondering if it's possible to do this SAME thing for Mac OS X. Like,

```
 ...
 return {
     isMac10.5: /mac osx 10.5/.test(userAgent),
     isMac10.6: /mac osx 10.6/.test(userAgent),
     isMac10.7: /mac osx 10.7/.test(userAgent),
     isMac10.8: /mac osx 10.8/.test(userAgent),
 };

 ....
 if(_os_.isMac10.5){
 OS = "Mac OS X Leopard";
 }

 etc., etc...
```

Any ideas? Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: `Windows detection code (works perfectly!)` perhaps for certain browsers in their default configurations. There is no standard for user agent strings, user agents can report whatever they want, it's unreliable and certainly not "perfect".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
return {
     isMac105: /Mac OS X 10_5/.test(userAgent),
     isMac106: /Mac OS X 10_6/.test(userAgent),
     isMac107: /Mac OS X 10_7/.test(userAgent),
     isMac108: /Mac OS X 10_8/.test(userAgent),
 };
```

useragent for mac e.g.

`Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_8_1) AppleWebKit/536.25 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/6.0 Safari/536.25`

`Macintosh; U; Intel Mac OS X 10_5_8; ru) AppleWebKit/533.18.1 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/5.0.2 Safari/533.18.5`

Comment: Can you use a dot in a property name?

Comment: This won't work in Firefox. The userAgent is: `"Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.6; rv:26.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/26.0"`

Answer (score 1):

Yeah it's because on Firefox the OSX Version is not listed as 10_6 but 10.6 So you have to add that specific line : isMac106: /Mac OS X 10.6/.test(userAgent)

Pay attention to the dot between 10 and 6