# Javascript for browser useragent - OS Verision

Tags: javascript

I have this code to redirect based on platform.  Is there a way to be even more specific on the Macintosh?  I need to set URLS by OS version, 10.5, 10.6, 10.7, etc.

```
<script language="JavaScript">
if (navigator.userAgent.indexOf("iPhone")!=-1) window.location = "http://example.com/ios.html";
if (navigator.userAgent.indexOf("Windows NT 6.1")!=-1) window.location = "http://example.com/windows7.html";
if (navigator.userAgent.indexOf("Windows NT 5.1")!=-1) window.location = "http://example.com/windowsxp.html";
if (navigator.userAgent.indexOf("Macintosh")!=-1) window.location = "http://example.com/macos.html";
if (navigator.userAgent.indexOf("Linux")!=-1) window.location = "http://example.com/linux.html";
</script>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to Detect Mac OS X Version in JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12451382/how-to-detect-mac-os-x-version-in-javascript)

Comment: If this is to find out what the browser supports then you're better off doing [feature detection](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.support/) instead.